# Tensorflow: Custom operation used in two networks simultaneously produces nan

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I have written following custom operation with gradient to binarize a real vector. (this code is inspired from https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342)

```
def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):

    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates:
    rnd_name = name+'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))

    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)  # see _MyBinarizerGrad for grad example
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)

def mycustombinarizer(x):
    if _test_:
        return x>0.5
    sess_ = tf.Session()
    probs = tf.constant(x)
    probs = tf.reshape(probs,[-1])
    probs = tf.pack([1-probs, probs], axis=1)
    probs = tf.log(probs/(1-probs))
    indexes = tf.multinomial(probs, 1)
    indexes = tf.cast(tf.reshape(indexes, list(x.shape)),tf.float32)
    with sess_.as_default():
        binary_x = indexes.eval()
    return binary_x

def binarizer(x, name=None):
    with ops.name_scope(name, "Binarizer", [x]) as name:
        sqr_x = py_func(mycustombinarizer,
                        [x],
                        [tf.float32],
                        name=name,
                        grad=_MyBinarizerGrad)  # <-- here's the call to the gradient
        return tf.reshape(sqr_x[0], tf.shape(x))

def _MyBinarizerGrad(op, grad):
    return grad
```

This works perfectly fine if there is just one network using this operation. But if I create two copies of the same network and use this binarizer operation and try to optimise the combined cost (cost_net1+cost_net2) then it produces nan cost after a few iterations.

```
def network_(x, netname):
    with tf.variable_scope(netname):
        x = someoperation(x)
        ...
        ret_tensor = binarizer(x,netname)

ypred1 = network_(input,'net1')
ypred2 = network_(input,'net2')
cost = costfn(ypred1,ytrue)+costfn(ypred2,ytrue)
```

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with the implementation of my custom function? Is it the problem with sessions to evaluate indexes.eval() in mycustombinarizer or is it problem with name_scope/ variable_scope or is it totally something. I am stuck here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this maybe.

```
@function.Defun()
def BinarizerGrad(unused_x, dy):
  # Backprop dy directly.
  return dy

@function.Defun(grad_func=BinarizerGrad)
def Binarizer(x):
  # your whatever forward function here. 
  return tf.floor(x + tf.random_uniform(tf.shape(x)))

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  y = Binarizer(x)
  dy = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  dx = tf.gradients(y, x, grad_ys=dy)

with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
  x_val = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]])
  dy_val = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0., 0.1, 0.9]])
  for v in sess.run([x, y, dx], feed_dict={x : x_val, dy: dy_val}):
    print v
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think building a graph, starting a session, and running is well-supported inside a py_func. In this case you can remove all those things and just use straight-up tensorflow code and everything should work.

Comment: I wrote a pyfunc to define custom gradient. How can I transform this code to get the custom gradient in tensorflow code

Comment: I don't think this is well-supported via the public API now.