# tensorboard: cannot open subgraph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Recently I wrote a my custom operator (and its gradient) in python following this post

[Tensorflow: Custom operation used in two networks simultaneously produces nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735766/tensorflow-custom-operation-used-in-two-networks-simultaneously-produces-nan)

Tensorflow runs with no error and the prediction gives expected accuracy. However, when I want to visualize this graph with tensorboard. I find that I cannot open the subgraph to see its structures. But it's gradient subgraph can be opened and seen. Does anyone has some idea about this problem?

Fig.1: subgraph fc1 cannot be opened but gradient/fc1 can be opened.

[image: Fig.1: subgraph fc1 cannot be opened but gradient/fc1 can be opened]

Comment: What happens when you try to click or double-click fc1?

Comment: In typical tensorboard, double clicking will unfold the fc1 block. But this time, it cannot unfold.

Comment: That `fc1` metanode should really be expandable. Could you please let me know if there are any errors in the developer console? Thank you! Additionally, if you are able to share the graph pbtxt file, I could reproduce this issue and take a closer look.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Please find the pbtxt file here: https://gist.github.com/4df5f4c27c49f3e3b99104d85fe80453.git

Comment: Are there any error messages that appear in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I can open the `fc1` metanode on TensorBoard 0.1.8.

[image]

What version of TensorBoard you are using? You can find the version via running

`python -c 'from tensorboard import version; print(version.VERSION)'`

After that, could you try upgrading tensorboard via

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow-tensorboard`

and let me know if the issue persists?

Comment: Hi, thank a lot! I am using 0.1.8 tensorboard as well. Do you mind share the code how do you visualize the pbtxt file with tensorboard? What I was doing is use 'summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(path, graph)' to save graphs and gets 'events.out.tfevents' file, which tensorboard reads.

Comment: Hi, thank a lot!  I tested this with 0.1.8 tensorboard bu still cannot open. Do you mind check it again?
 Thanks! https://github.com/zhacmsra/tensorboard_graph_test.git

Comment: Hi @zhangc, that seems correct. I don't have any code to show. I just uploaded your pbtxt. Do you see any errors in the [Chrome console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) when you try to expand the problematic node?